# Having trouble finding [f(a)]^2 and f(a + h) when f(x) = 3x^2 − x + 3

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

I was given the function f(x) and have to find f(xyz variation). Right now I'm trying to find [f(a)]^2 and f(a + h). I wasn't sure how to do these, but for [f(a)]^2 I started out with:

[f(a)]^2=[3(a)^2-a]^2+3, foiled (3a^2-a)(3a^2-a) and got 9a^4-6a^3+a^2.

For f(a+h) I started out with:

f(a+h)=3(a+h)^2-a+h+3, foiled (a+h)(a+h) and got a^2+2ah+h^2, then I distributed 3 and got 3a^2+6ah+3h^2 and got 3a^2+6ah+3h^2-a+h+3.

The website that I got the problem from tells me that these two solutions are wrong, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: For your first expression, it looks like you've computed $(3a^2-a)^2+3$ and you need to compute $(3a^2-a+3)^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is actually not so wrong.

As Matthew pointed out in the comments, in the first the square should be applied to the whole expression:

$$(f(a))^2=(3a^2-a+3)^2=9a^4+a^2+9-6a^3-6a+18a^2=9a^4-6a^3+19a^2-6a+9$$

where I used $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2ac+2bc$

In the second you missed a minus: always use parenthesis to avoid such mistake.
$$f(a+h)=3(a+h)^2-(a+h)+3=3a^2+6ah+3h^2-a{\color{red}-}h+3$$

Answer (score 0):

Given $f(x)=3x^2-x+3$,

\begin{align}
[f(a)]^2&=(3a^2-a+3)^2\\
&=(3a^2-a+3)(3a^2-a+3)\\
&= \textrm{you take it from here}
\end{align}

For your solution involving $f(a+h)$, you forgot to distribute the negative.  Remember to always substitute into brackets!